# Should the notion of continuity, usually ascribed to Cauchy, be ascribed to Leibniz?

Tags: real-analysis, math-history, philosophy

In his text, *Deleuze and the History of Mathematics*, Simon Duffy writes:

> Leibniz also thought the following to be a requirement to continuity:
>   "When the difference between two instances in a given series, or in whatever is presupposed, can be diminished until it becomes smaller than any given quantity whatever, the corresponding difference in what is sought, or what results, must of neccesity also be diminshed or become less than any given quantity whatever".
>
> Leibniz, Philosophical Papers and Letters, 2nd ed, Ed & Trans. L.Loemker

This sounds very close to the traditional epsilon & delta method of undergraduate analysis which I'd been taught had originated with Cauchy.

How far should Leibniz be credited with the idea of continuity as traditionally understood in mathematics?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just interested in the "epsilon-delta" idea (rather than continuity per se)... Archimedes "method of exhaustion" may qualify.

[LINK](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/Archimedes.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the notion of continuity should be ascribed to Cauchy *alone*; here's a picture from the [*Cours d'Analyse*](http://books.google.it/books?id=wAsOAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=cours%20d%27analyse%20cauchy&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BZrzUt_UK8T_ygPqvIC4Cg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=cours%20d%27analyse%20cauchy&f=false)

#### Page 34

[image: page 34]

#### Page 35

[image]

This is really vague, because it relies on the concept of infinitesimal. Of course this *is* the idea of continuity in the modern sense, but only when we change it into what Weierstraß precisely defined in terms of $\varepsilon$-$\delta$. Also Heine should be mentioned, with continuity defined in terms of convergence of sequences.

Leibniz cannot be credited: he didn't even think to cases where functions are not continuous.

Comment: Cauchy's comment is not vague; nor is the concept of infinitesimal vague. Weierstrass proposed one formalisation; Robinson proposed another that is closer to Cauchy's original intention.

Comment: Ok, its my memory thats probably faulty here, Weierstrass definition, is as you say, the one I was thinking of.

Comment: @user72694 Robinson introduced a *precise* notion of infinitesimals; the concept used by Cauchy *was* vague and contradictory.

Comment: @egreg, this is somewhat simplistic. By the standard you are proposing, all mathematics done before 1870 is vague and contradictory; however, most historians don't subscribe to this view as far as Gauss and Dirichlet are concerned, for example. You also provide no evidence that Cauchy's notion was contradictory. I realize this is part of the ethos created by the calculus textbooks; however this is all the more reason to be careful in offering historical judgments.

Comment: @MoziburUllah, this is correct: Weierstrass is the source of the epsilon, delta technique though some authors credit an even earlier paper by Dirichlet. As far as Cauchy is concerned, it is not your memory that is faulty; both calculus textbooks and "survey" history books are full of incorrect claims concerning Cauchy.

Comment: @user72694 I surely don't want to diminish Cauchy's great contribution to mathematics; but attributing the notion of continuity to Cauchy alone would make no justice to those who gave the *correct* definition, without recourse to intuition of infinitesimals.

Comment: @egreg, I understand your corcern but I don't fully understand your position. As you acknowledged above, Robinson gave a fully rigorous definition of continuity using infinitesimals. The definition is identical to Cauchy's procedurally.  What is lacking of course is the set-theoretic *ontology* commonly taken for granted today. But by that standard everything before 1870 would have to be declared vague at best and contradictory at worst, because set theory was not available yet. Some of these issues are discussed in more detail in my various questions.

Comment: @user72694 I added "alone", that probably clarifies my opinion on the subject. Cauchy opened the way, Weierstraß paved it.

Comment: @egreg, the attribution of the notion of continuity to Cauchy is completely uncontroversial and is accepted by most historians. Of course, Weierstrass provided a formalisation that was a major breakthrough because at the time there was no satisfactory theory of infinitesimals yet, but this does not subtract from Cauchy's priority. What is controversial is the *nature* of Cauchy's definition. Inspite of the clear evidence that you provided in your answer, many historians claim that Cauchy gave an epsilon, delta definition! The article I linked in my answer provides a detailed analysis.

Answer (score 0):

"the traditional epsilon & delta method of undergraduate analysis which I'd been taught had originated with Cauchy": you have been taught a misconception. Cauchy defined continuity as follows: if $\alpha$ is infinitesimal then $f(x+\alpha)-f(x)$ is also infinitesimal. See [Cours d'Analyse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cours_d%27Analyse). Notice that there are no epsilons or deltas here, only infinitesimals. Cauchy consistently gave this definition of continuity starting in his 1821 textbook until as late as his 1853 paper clarifying the hypothesis of his "sum theorem"; see [this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1162/POSC_a_00047). As you noticed, Leibniz authored very similar formulations but did not really think of this as a property of functions (which weren't introduced until Euler). More on Leibniz [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80364/in-what-ways-did-leibnizs-philosophy-foresee-modern-mathematics/127933#127933).

For a recent paper trying to set the record straight on Cauchy you can read [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10699-011-9235-x).